# How do I detect that a popover has finished?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

In my OS X app built with Swift, I show a popover when the user is not logged in. The user logs in via the popover. How do I then detect at the view controller that launched the popover that the popover has been dismissed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Koen mentioned, you should check `NSPopoverDidCloseNotification` and call a method, if the popover did close:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().notificationCenter.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: "popOverClosed:",
    name:NSPopoverDidCloseNotification,
    object: nil
)
```

That way the `popOverClosed` method gets called everytime the popover dismisses.

```
func popOverClosed(sender : AnyObject) {
    //PopOver Dismissed
}
```

Comment: He's using OSX, not iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the `NSPopoverDidCloseNotification` notification.